# Strange issue using sudo

Tags: 14.04, sudo

When I try to use `sudo` this is what happens

```
chris@vaio:~$ sudo 
sudo: 424273033461091241000: invalid value
```

except that doesn't do it justice:

[image]

I have been having issues with the latest kernel(.30) and finally was able to boot into an older kernel(.29) and it's working somewhat, but now this has happened.

Doesn't matter if I add anything after `sudo` or not, it's still the same 'invalid value'

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `sudo` aliased to something? Check with `alias sudo`.

Comment: No it isn't aliased